# No connection to server from the internet - how to know if the router blocks it?

Tags: router, raspberry-pi, isp, home-server

I don't know much about network-related issues. I am trying to set up a small web server on a Raspberry Pi. I have the latest Raspberry Pi OS and installed Apache on it, and when opening the local IP address of the server in my browser it works fine, I can see the Apache welcome page. The issue comes when I try to access it from the outside, with the external IP address.

I went to my router settings to set up port forwarding for port 80 (the default for HTTP, if I understood correctly), and also port 443 (for HTTPS, just in case). When I enter the external IP address in a browser, nothing loads and the connection times out. Since it works fine with the internal IP address, I suppose the issue is with the router not allowing traffic to reach the server (or maybe the ISP is blocking inbound traffic?), but I have no idea how to make sure of that. Or maybe there is something I missed when setting up the server ?

I know that ISPs can change IP addresses sometimes, but mine didn't change at any time during the test I did. The router is a CGN5-AP of Hitron and the ISP is Taiwan Mobile.

Edit: [screenshot of my router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egesh.png)

Comment: When you are entering the external IP into the address bar, are you also using the port number? (e.g http://127.0.0.1:80). Also can you specify how you setup your port-forwarding? It could help others give you a more specific answer.

Comment: You're correct about the ports. You should give your RasPi a static IP to exclude any problems that failing DHCP might cause. Then, if the port forwarding is correctly configured, you just need open a browser outside your network and go to `https://your.external.ip` the traffic should be directed to your RasPi. Can you post a screenshot showing the port forwarding in your router?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to yourself via the internet? If yes, the router might not support it. Try for example from your phone, from truly outside your local network.

Comment: I tried both with and without specifying the port. I also tried to connect with my phone on mobile data, none of it worked. I added a screenshot of the port forwarding settings.

Comment: Some ISPs block 'common' hosting ports. Its also worth checking to see if your IP external to your network is a 'real' IP or a CGN IP

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your port forwarding. If you're connecting with a different system to a phone hotspot and can't access the server with the public IP, it might be time to call the ISP and verify if incoming connections are allowed and if they are NATting the incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I called my ISP. Due to language barrier I couldn't explain the whole problem and I ended up just asking for a fixed IP address. They sent a technician and now it works.
I'm not sure whether they only gave me a fixed IP or did something else too, but now I can connect from the outside.